# How to find a max value of letters in the rows of a 2D array

Tags: c

I have a 3 row, 10 column array. Each column is designated to a person, each of the 3 spaces in every column is a yes or no response ('y', or 'n').

I'm trying to find the highest number of 'n' values in a column and setting it as a max value to compare it to the other columns.

How would I got about using if statements to find the number of 'n' elements in a column and overwriting a variable when a column with a larger amount of 'n' elements is reached?

I've been trying to test only the first set of indices of the 2D array, so rather than testing every box, I only test the 10 columns

If a certain column has 3 'n' values (all the boxes in that column are 'n') then the max value should be 3.
however, if the highest number of 'n' elements in any column is only 2 then the max value should be 2.

Comment: Please post some code and the type declarations used.

Comment: Divide the problem. First count and store the results into array of `10`. Then find the maximum. After you are done, you can try and combine these two into something more concise.

Comment: You should start with sowing us an example. Without [mcve] no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the future please be more specific about your problem and it would help us to show some code so we can have more of an understanding of your problem. I have an example but it was written on ipad so might not be fully working but it'll help you to get an idea of what to do.

I just created an int array where 1=true, 0 = false. it will go through columns first and then compare values of neg vs pos and store whichever is greater in a max variable. Again, this is a very basic probably buggy code but will give a headstart!

Cheers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int pos = 0;
  int neg = 0;
  int max = 0;
  int array[3][10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      if (array[i][j] == 1){
        pos++;
      }else if ( array[i][j] == 0){
        neg++;
      }
    }
    if (pos > neg){
      max = pos;
    }else{max = neg;}
  }
  return 0;
}
```